# Problem with Flickering on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: drivers, display, screen, radeon, amd-graphics

I have some problem with flickering when watching movies on youtube and scrolling pages. It can be found in "Program & Uppdateringar" (software and updates?) but says its "okänd, Använder Processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs från amd64-microcode (proprietär)" (unknown) so I selected it but it didn't do anything when restart ubuntu. I then tried "xdiagnose" and checked "Inaktivera grafik för starthanterare" and "Inaktivera drivrutin för VESA-framebuffer" and "Inaktivera PAT-minne" and restarted, it was a bit better but still flickering.

I have installed with the Swedish language.

I did write in the Terminal `lshw -c video` and got this, I don't know if this help, or you need something else or more:

```
  *-display               
       beskrivning: VGA compatible controller
       produkt: Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
       tillverkare: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 45
       bredd: 64 bits
       klocka: 33MHz
       förmågor: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       konfiguration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resurser: irq:35 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f07fffff ioport:4000(storlek=256) memory:f0e00000-f0e3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Well, installing the microcode won't help the flickering at all. They are completely unrelated.

Comment: I hope there is a solution for this.